# Create custom reports in Google Analytics that are available to all users?

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics has a Custom Reports feature which allows me to list and filter various metrics. I've discovered that these Custom Reports are only available to the user that created them.

Is there some feature that would allow me to create something like a Custom Report such that it is automatically visible to all users of the Account Property View?